# Why the case of independence of random variables is more important than any other specific type of dependence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Maybe a stupid question but why is the case of independence of, say, two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is in some ways considered to be more ``central'' or more important than any other type of fixed dependence between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Other type, such as what?

Comment: @Michael : not completely sure but let's e.g. consider Joe's measure of multivariate association. Joe's measure is equal to 0 iff the variables are independent. Why is the case of that measure being zero more important than cases when that measure is equal to, say, 0.5?

Comment: @Alik, one thing to add to your comment above is that you assume that $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density.